# Rostopic pub equivalent in Python

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am working with a simulated bebop2
These are the commands I am using to run the simulation.

```
sphinx /opt/parrot-sphinx/usr/share/sphinx/drones/bebop2.drone

roslaunch bebop_driver bebop_node.launch ip:=10.202.0.1
```

In this case ***bebop_driver*** is the subscriber and ***bebop_commander*** the publisher( see code below)

I've been using:

```
rostopic pub -r 10 cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

in order to publish to ***cmd_vel*** topic successfully .I need to publish the same message to the same topic using a Python script, but so far I haven't been able.

This is the Python script I am trying to use :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy

from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

import sys

rospy.init_node("bebop_commander")
movement_publisher= rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist , queue_size=10)
movement_cmd = Twist()

speed = float(sys.argv[1])
time = float(sys.argv[2])

print ("Adelante")

if speed != "" and speed > 0 : 

    print ("Velocidad =" , speed , "m/s")

else:

    print ("Falta parametro de velocidad o el valor es incorrecto")

if time != "" and time > 0 :

    print ("Tiempo = ",time, "s")

else:

    print ("Falta parametro de tiempo o el valor es incorrecto")

if time != "" and time > 0 : 


   movement_cmd.linear.x = 0
   movement_cmd.linear.y = 0
   movement_cmd.linear.z = 0 
   movement_cmd.angular.x = 0 
   movement_cmd.angular.y = 0               
   movement_cmd.angular.z = 0 

   movement_publisher.publish(movement_msg)

   print ("Publishing")

rospy.spin()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few mistakes/suggestions in your code:

- You are not checking if the user is actually entering all the arguments at the start, namely filename, speed and time. Here try using below code:

  ```
  if len(sys.argv)>2:
     speed = float(sys.argv[1])
     time = float(sys.argv[2]) 
  else:
     print("one or more arguments missing!!")
  ```
- There is no need of `speed != ""` and `time != ""` once you checked `len(sys.argv)>2` condition.
- you are passing an unknown variable `movement_msg` inside `movement_publisher.publish()`. Kindly check below line:

  ```
  movement_publisher.publish(movement_msg)
  ```

  It should be `movement_cmd`.

**Modified code(Tested):**

Filename: `test_publisher.py`

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
import sys

rospy.init_node("bebop_commander")
movement_publisher= rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist , queue_size=10)
movement_cmd = Twist()

if len(sys.argv)>2:
    speed = float(sys.argv[1])
    time = float(sys.argv[2])  
    print("Adelante")
    if speed > 0.0:
        print("Velocidad =" , speed , "m/s")      
    else:
        print("Falta parametro de velocidad o el valor es incorrecto") 
    if time > 0.0:
        print ("Tiempo = ",time, "s")
        movement_cmd.linear.x = 0
        movement_cmd.linear.y = 0
        movement_cmd.linear.z = 0
        movement_cmd.angular.x = 0
        movement_cmd.angular.y = 0              
        movement_cmd.angular.z = 0
        movement_publisher.publish(movement_cmd)
        print ("Publishing")
        rospy.spin()      
    else:
        print ("Falta parametro de tiempo o el valor es incorrecto")     
else:
    print('one or more argument is missing!!')
```

**Note:** Don't forget to copy the file `test_publisher.py` to `scripts` directory and make it executable via `chmod +x test_publisher.py`

Output:

(Terminal 1): Run `roscore` command. You must have a `roscore` running in order for `ROS` nodes to communicate.

[image]

(Terminal 2): Run python `publisher` file with arguments.

[image]

(Terminal 3): checking `rostopic` information

[image]

Comment: I changed my code as suggested but still the simulated drone is not moving.I am checking the published message using `rostopic echo cmd_vel` and nothing is appearing.Only when I use the first command I showed I read info in the echo terminal and the drone moves.

Comment: Yeah. It won't move.

Comment: Because in your code linear as well angular velocity components are 0.

Comment: You are taking speed and time as inputs but doing nothing with it.

Comment: This solution just helps you create a rostopic publisher using  python and solves your above problem.

Comment: In order to move the drone, you will have to create a subscriber along with publisher. Publisher publishes data on the topic and the subscriber subscribe to that common topic and consume it.

Comment: I updated the question with more info about what I’m doing.I am able to control my drone with the command I mentioned, but when I run the python script no message appears even though _rostopic info cmd_vel_ is telling me that _bebop_driver_ is the subscriber and _bebop_commander_ the publisher

Comment: @SebastiánMayorgaCastro, this now became a completely different question and there is no subscriber in the code, by the way. So please post a completely new question for that and you post both publisher and subscriber part. For a reference, check out this: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

Comment: I created a new question, I think my main issue is that my python script is not even publishing to *cmd_vel* topic.

Comment: @SebastiánMayorgaCastro, please provide link to the question and if you think above solution solved your problem of how to code rostopic pub equivalent in Python, kindly accept it.

Comment: Here it is (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773936/publisher-subscriber-issues-when-using-rostopic-pub)