# Publisher/Subscriber issues when using rostopic pub

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am working with a simulated bebop 2 ,these are the commands I am using to run the simulation.

```
sphinx /opt/parrot-sphinx/usr/share/sphinx/drones/bebop2.drone

roslaunch bebop_driver bebop_node.launch ip:=10.202.0.1
```

When using the following command I am able to move the drone succesfuly

```
rostopic pub -r 10 cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

What Im trying to do is to move the drone with the python script I am showing below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy

from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

import sys

rospy.init_node("bebop_commander")
movement_publisher= rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist , queue_size=10)
movement_cmd = Twist()

speed = float(sys.argv[1])
time = float(sys.argv[2])

print ("Adelante")

if speed != "" and speed > 0 : 

    print ("Velocidad =" , speed , "m/s")

else:

    print ("Falta parametro de velocidad o el valor es incorrecto")

if time != "" and time > 0 :

    print ("Tiempo = ",time, "s")

else:

    print ("Falta parametro de tiempo o el valor es incorrecto")

if time != "" and time > 0 : 


   movement_cmd.linear.x = 0
   movement_cmd.linear.y = 0
   movement_cmd.linear.z = 0 
   movement_cmd.angular.x = 0 
   movement_cmd.angular.y = 0               
   movement_cmd.angular.z = 0 

   movement_publisher.publish(movement_cmd)

   print ("Publishing")

rospy.spin()
```

In this case ***bebop_driver*** is subscribed to *cmd_vel* and ***bebop_commander*** publishes to *cmd_vel* topic.I checked this by using `rostopic info cmd_vel` and I got:

```
Type: geometry_msgs/Twist

Publishers: 
 * /bebop_commander (http://sebastian-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:40043/)

Subscribers: 
 * /bebop_driver (http://sebastian-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:46591/)
```

But still I am not getting any message when checking the topic using `rostopic echo cmd_vel`

I think my main issue is that my python script is not even publishing to *cmd_vel* topic.

***Edit***

Here is my ***bebop_node.launch*** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
   <arg name="namespace" default="bebop" />
   <arg name="ip" default="10.202.0.1" />
   <arg name="drone_type" default="bebop2" /> <!-- available drone types: bebop1, bebop2 -->
   <arg name="config_file" default="$(find bebop_driver)/config/defaults.yaml" />
   <arg name="camera_info_url" default="package://bebop_driver/data/$(arg drone_type)_camera_calib.yaml" />
       <node pkg="bebop_driver" name="bebop_driver" type="bebop_driver_node" output="screen">
           <param name="camera_info_url" value="$(arg camera_info_url)" />
           <param name="bebop_ip" value="$(arg ip)" />
           <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg config_file)" />
       </node>
       <include file="$(find bebop_description)/launch/description.launch" />

</launch>
```

Comment: Please add the launch file.

Comment: I added the launch file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `rostopic info` shows that the publisher is connected, then it is. I think that your issue is that the publisher publishes at most once to that topic.

I've modified your code to make it look like the one available at ROS [tutorials](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(python)).

I'll explain it, as it's short:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
```

You certainly know that all python ROS node starts with the python [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Then, in your code, the imports for system module, rospy and the Twist message.

```
def commander(speed, time):
    movement_publisher = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist , queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node("bebop_commander", anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    movement_cmd = Twist()
```

Then, I've changed you code into a function, `commander`. It creates the publisher and initializes the node. Then a `Rate` object is created; with it you can loop at 10 Hz, and publish the message at 10 Hz, the same a the `-r 10` argument of your `rostopic pub` command. After that, the Twist message is created, for it will be used multiple times.

```
    while not rospy.is_shutdown(): 
        movement_cmd.linear.x = 0
        movement_cmd.linear.y = 0
        movement_cmd.linear.z = 0 
        movement_cmd.angular.x = 0 
        movement_cmd.angular.y = 0               
        movement_cmd.angular.z = 0 
        rospy.logdebug("Publishing")
        movement_publisher.publish(movement_cmd)
        rate.sleep()
```

The loop checks the `rospy.is_shutdown()` flag to check if it should stop, because the node was told to (for example, by means of a `ctrl+c`). Then it fills the Twist message, logs a debug string, and publishes the command message. `rate.sleep()` implements a delay, so the node can publish messages at the desired rate, instead of doing it at full speed (which depends on your PC).

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    speed = float(sys.argv[1])
    time = float(sys.argv[2])
```

The conditional is there to make the script execute the body of the `if` when the node is called, but not when the script is imported as a module (it's a standard python idiom). Then it converts the arguments as you do.

```
    if speed > 0:
        rospy.logdebug("Velocidad = %s m/s", speed)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Falta parametro de velocidad o el valor es incorrecto")
```

Checks the speed value, logs a debug message if everything is ok, and raises an exception if not. That will kill the node. The same is done for `time`.

```
    try:
        commander(speed, time)
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Finally, the `commander()` is called until an exception is caught. If the exception is `rospy.ROSInterruptException`, meaning the user pressed `CTRL+C`, it silences it and the node exits.

The complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

def commander(speed, time):
    movement_publisher = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist , queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node("bebop_commander", anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    movement_cmd = Twist()

    while not rospy.is_shutdown(): 
        movement_cmd.linear.x = 0
        movement_cmd.linear.y = 0
        movement_cmd.linear.z = 0 
        movement_cmd.angular.x = 0 
        movement_cmd.angular.y = 0               
        movement_cmd.angular.z = 0 
        rospy.logdebug("Publishing")
        movement_publisher.publish(movement_cmd)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    speed = float(sys.argv[1])
    time = float(sys.argv[2])

    rospy.logdebug("Adelante") # Use rospy.logdebug() for debug messages.

    if speed > 0:
        rospy.logdebug("Velocidad = %s m/s", speed)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Falta parametro de velocidad o el valor es incorrecto")

    if time > 0 :
        rospy.logdebug("Tiempo = %s s", time)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Falta parametro de tiempo o el valor es incorrecto")

    try:
        commander(speed, time)
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Comment: It is working now, just please change  _movement_publisher.publish_  argument from  _movement_msg_  to  _movement_cmd_  , I copied wrong the argument